Adder and subtractor VHDL
can anybody maybe help me to implement a component that can add and subtract two 8-bit numbers in two's complement ? An overflow does not have to be taken into account, so an 8-bit result is generated. I always get incorrect calculation results in my testbench. Some of them are correct.
15 + 10 = 0
11 + 2 = 13
19 - 46 = -27
15 - 10 = 4
-128 - -128 = -1

Appreciate any kind of help!
library IEEE; use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
entity add_sub is
    port(a, b: in STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
         sub: in STD_ULOGIC;
         result: out STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0));
end;

architecture Behavioral of add_sub is
begin
    process (a, b, sub)
        variable temp_result : STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        variable carry : STD_ULOGIC := '0';
    begin
        if sub = '1' then
            -- Subtraction
            for i in 0 to 7 loop
                temp_result(i) := (a(i) xor b(i) xor carry);
                carry := ((not a(i) and b(i)) or (b(i) and carry) or (carry and not a(i)));
            end loop;
        else
            -- Addition
            for i in 0 to 7 loop
                temp_result(i) := (a(i) xor b(i) xor carry);
                carry := ((a(i) and b(i)) or (b(i) and carry) or (carry and a(i)));
            end loop;
        end if;

        result <= temp_result;
    end process;
end Behavioral;


You try to subtract (a-b) by adding: temp_result(i) := (a(i) xor b(i) xor carry). But then you must negate b before adding. This can be achieved by inverting b and setting the carry to 1 at bit 0. Also the carry calculation is then the same for subtracting and adding.

Carry should be assigned to a '1' prior to the loop statement for subtraction and to a '0' for addition before it's loop statement.  Process statement object declarations (here variable carry) are only initialized once during elaboration and carry will hold it's value across the suspension and resumption of the process. Provide a [mcve], a testbench with expected as well actual results. See [ask].

The carry assignment expression for subtraction should be identical to that found in addition, avoiding any possible ambiguity in Matthias' otherwise concise comment describing subtraction as adding the two's complement of the subtrahend.

In general using process like this for defining adder and subtractor is not the best way. Try this one instead for adder and do the same for sub:
--
-- A for-generate example
--
-- for_generate.vhd
--
entity for_generate is
port(
A, B : in BIT_VECTOR(0 to 7);
CIN : in BIT;
SUM : out BIT_VECTOR(0 to 7);
COUT : out BIT
);
end for_generate;

architecture archi of for_generate is
signal C : BIT_VECTOR(0 to 8);
begin
C(0) <= CIN;
COUT <= C(8);
LOOP_ADD : for I in 0 to 7 generate
SUM(I) <= A(I) xor B(I) xor C(I);
C(I + 1) <= (A(I) and B(I)) or (A(I) and C(I)) or (B(I) and C(I));
end generate;
end archi;

